# How to pass data between two forms (components) in different pages using react js with meteor js?

Tags: forms, meteor, reactjs

I have a page with a **component thas is a form** that has 2 input texts: **name** and **email**:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} action="register">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Name"
      value={this.state.name}
      onChange={this.handlNameChange}
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Email"
      value={this.state.email}
      onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
    />
    <button className="btn btn-success btn-block">Cadastre-se</button>
</form>
```

I want to pass the data from these two inputs to another page called register (is the action of the form) that has its own component form. In register I have a similar structure form but with a lot more inputs.

The router looks like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="about" component={About} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Router>
```

How can I pass the data from one form/component to another in different pages?

How can I access the data in the other page's component (Register)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pass data from **Form of page 1** to **Form of page 2** using [u2622:persistent-session](https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session) package.

Form page 1:

```
handleSubmit: function(e){
  Session.setPersistent({name: this.state.name, email: this.state.email});
}
```

Form page 2:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    name: Session.get("name"),
    email: Session.get("email")
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, using [`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) is probably the most simple.

```js
handleSubmit() {
  Session.set("name", this.state.name);
  Session.set("email", this.state.email);
}
```

And in your `Register` component:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    name: Session.get("name"),
    email: Session.get("email")
  });
}
```

http://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html

Comment: Won't Session be lost after form submission (page redirect to Register)?

Comment: No, Session shouldn't be lost.

Comment: That's strange. Tested your solution but it did not work. The u2622:persistent-session package worked like a charm. Thanks for helping.